# quotient ring which is not local

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Given $R:=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2)$,

I want to show that this is not a local ring. So can I just apply the Nullstellensatz and create two different maximal ideals? Let's say $(\bar{x},\bar{y},\bar{z})$ and $(\bar{x}-1,\bar{y},\bar{z})$.
How can I show that 
$R/ (\bar{x},\bar{y},\bar{z})$ and $R/ (\bar{x}-1,\bar{y},\bar{z})$ are both isomorphic to the field $\mathbb{C}$ in order to show that both ideals are maximal?

Comment: You should not fear to write $R/(x-a) = \Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(xy-z^2,x-a)=\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]/(ay-z^2,x-a)$ $=\Bbb{C}[x]/(x-a)[y,z]/(ay-z^2)\cong \Bbb{C}[y,z]/(ay-z^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t even think it takes the Nulstellensatz.  If it were local, all of its quotients would be local, and would not have any nontrivial idempotents.

But look: the quotient by the ideal generated by $x-z$ and $y-1$ has $z$ as a nontrivial idempotent.